# Set Cookie before Spring Security Filter Chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I would like to set a referrer cookie as I need to exclude some pages (e.g. error, login, logout, ...) to be able to redirect to the last called but not excluded page after login:

```
public class CookieReferrerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    public static final String REFERRER_COOKIE_NAME = "REFERRER";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (!isReferrerExcluded(request)) {
            Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie(REFERRER_COOKIE_NAME, request.getRequestURI());
            sessionCookie.setPath(!"".equals(request.getContextPath()) ? request.getContextPath() : "/");
            sessionCookie.setSecure(false);
            sessionCookie.setMaxAge(-1);

            response.addCookie(sessionCookie);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private boolean isReferrerExcluded(HttpServletRequest request) {
        for (String pattern : EXCLUDED_REFERRER) {
            if (new AntPathRequestMatcher(pattern).matches(request)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

But Spring Security Filter Chain getting triggered before CookieReferrerFilter.
So calling a secured page will redirect me immediately to the login page without calling `CookieReferrerFilter.doFilterInternal` before and no cookie is set.

There's a class configuring the webbapp (setting config classes, mappings, filters) which extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ApplicationContextConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CookieReferrerFilter cookieReferrerFilter = new CookieReferrerFilter();

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        return new Filter[] { cookieReferrerFilter, characterEncodingFilter };
    }
}
```

and another one which simply extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`:

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Comment: [The Security Filter Chain](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Java-based configuration of Spring Security, you can just let your filter be spring managed and add it at the start of the Spring Security filter chain (heavily inspired from example in the HttpSecurity javadoc (see below for a link):

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class HttpSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Autowired  CookieReferrerFilter cookieFilter;

     @Autowired CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter;

     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
             .addFilterBefore(cookieFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
             .addFilterBefore(encodingFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
               //your configuration follows here
                ; 
      }
   }
```

See http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#addFilter(javax.servlet.Filter) for details on this.